# How can I display the data from my Firebase Database in my web site?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

On Firebase, I am having the following issue; my data being structured as this:

```
myApp
- myList
    - KKJJXX...1        myString: "String One"
    - KKJJXX...2        myString: "String Two"
    - KKJJXX...3        myString: "String Three"
```

I want to make some JavaScript (in a web page of mine) to list the values of myString in the DB above.
Here is what I came up with after digging the web. It works to a point, but not quite.
I can see in the debugging console of my browser that I have got the data I want. I write my concerns more precisely after the script.

```
<script>
var ref = new Firebase("https://myApp.firebaseio.com/myList/");

ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    for (x in snapshot.val()) {
        var xRef = new Firebase("https://myApp.firebaseio.com/myList/"+x+"/");
        xRef.once("value", function(xsnapshot) {
            var name = xsnapshot.child("myString");
            console.log(name);
        });
    }
}, function (errorObject) {
    console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
</script>
```

In the debugging console I get this line(3 times):

```
Object { A: Object, Y: Object, g: Object }
```

And I can see that the A Object contains the information I am looking for (myString).
What should I change in the script above to list directly the contents of myString on the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `child`, you're getting a new `FirebaseReference` -- not a data snapshot.  You'd need to `.on('value')` it to fetch the ref's data, but that would be silly because you already have the data.

Instead, just stash the snapshot's data in a local variable and operate over that.

```
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    for (x in snapshot.val()) {
        var xRef = new Firebase("https://myApp.firebaseio.com/myList/"+x+"/");
        xRef.once("value", function(xsnapshot) {
            var data = xsnapshot.val();
            var name = data["myString"];
            console.log(name);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you.